# Need help appying color to the background using color picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-color as my color picker. `console.log('Current color:', this.state.color);` outputs color in **rgba** value. So what I want to achieve is changing component colors with a color picker value. Really amateurish I know, what I tried so far was adding classes to divs and with React Helmet:

```
export class Intro extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Style>
      {
        .intro:hover {
          background-color: red;
        }
      }
      </Style>
    )
  }
}
```

This wrote it perfectly fine inside `</head>` tags. And all elements with that class changed the color. When I tried to use this state inside the bracket, it rendered as a raw text `color={ this.state.color }` inside the style tags. This is the closest workaround I've got. I had no luck setting inline styles into an existing component.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the first option in [this article](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822). I think you're mixing terminology. `export class` is not a css class, that's a javascript ES6 class. CSS goes inside an object and can be passed inline to a DOM element. If you want to use the `:hover` selector, you'll have to assign a `className` to the element you are wanting to apply this to and import a css file. This is the example I have below.

file.css

```
.intro:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

file.jsx

```
export class Intro extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="intro">some contents</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems I didn't explain myself clearly. I know how to add styles from .css file. What I want to achieve is that color value is dynamic related to the one I picked from color-picker. That hover thing is a random style I show as an example. Let's say I got 5 divs which are all different components and I want to theme them according to the color-picker color value. That is my question, what I need to do in order to achieve that. Color will be dynamic always, some static classes wont work in this scenario. In app.js I use this "import SketchExample from './colorpicker'" this will make it render.